# How to refer to a 'related' table in another excel table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created two related tables (tableA and tableB) in excel and linked them using 'Relationships' in Excel 2013. I'm trying to create a new formula field in tableB that refers to two cells from a matching unique ID row. I cannot find a structured reference way of doing this and could use your help!

Here is the pseudocode for the calculated field in tableB, where Column1 would house the linked unique ID:

=RANDBETWEEN(tableA[Column2], tableA[Column3])

Of course, these tableA references return the entire column, not just the linked and related cell.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in the data model. Add both tables to the data model and use

To add to the data model. Choose to analyse the table with a pivot and select "add to data model".

Unfortunately, although the data model is a built-in feature, Microsoft haven't seen fit to provide a proper interface to it so to manipulate it directly, you need to install the [Microsoft PowerQuery addin](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/whats-new-in-the-power-query-march-2014-release-HA104220547.aspx).